First std::mutex::lock() crashes in application built with latest Visual Studio 2022
Recently I installed the latest Visual Studio 2022 v17.10 to build my programs, and initially all went well. But after some other program installation, my programs started failing immediately on start where the first std::mutex::lock() is called with the exception

0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000.

and stack trace:
msvcp140.dll!mtx_do_lock(_Mtx_internal_imp_t * mtx, const xtime * target) Line 100  C++
[Inline Frame] my.dll!std::_Mutex_base::lock()
[Inline Frame] my.dll!std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::{ctor}(std::mutex &)

It turned out that the installed application was built in a previous version of Visual Studio 2022, and it silently downgraded C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll to version 14.34.31931.0, where the exception happens.
I personally managed to restore normal operation of my programs, by pressing Repair in Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2022 Redistributable (x64) - 14.40.33810, which restored C:\Windows\System32\msvcp140.dll to version 14.40.33810.0.
But since this unexpected crash on start-up can easily happen to the users of my program, I would like to ask, is there a way to make the programs built in the latest Visual Studio 2022 compatible with runtimes from previous versions of the same Visual Studio 2022? Or at least how to show meaningful error to the users if the runtime is downgraded for some reason instead of silent application termination.

Short answer, use the _DISABLE_CONSTEXPR_MUTEX_CONSTRUCTOR preprocessor macro.
This nugget of info from the Microsoft/STL changelog might help us understand the visual studio snafu that unfolded over the past couple days.

Fixed mutex's constructor to be constexpr. #3824 #4000 #4339 Note:
Programs that aren't following the documented restrictions on binary
compatibility may encounter null dereferences in mutex machinery. You
must follow this rule: When you mix binaries built by different
supported versions of the toolset, the Redistributable version must be
at least as new as the latest toolset used by any app component.
You can define _DISABLE_CONSTEXPR_MUTEX_CONSTRUCTOR as an escape
hatch.
--- microsoft/STL changelog

I ran into similar issue on a GitHub Actions workflow and arrived here from these independently reported issues in the Visual Studio developer community:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/All-my-std::unique_lock-crashed-after-th/10665376?space=41&sort=newest&viewtype=all
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Access-violation-in-_Thrd_yield-after-up/10664660
https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/10004

You can find a detailed breakdown - https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/10004#issuecomment-2156109231

I wish I had found this before spending several hours on debugging this crash. But at least now I can confirm that this is indeed the correct answer.

This is still an issue as of VS2022 Version 17.11.3. I got it from using httplib in my project that was compiled with an older version. The clash between the two kicked up this error. Thanks @hyperion1010 for the clear answer!

I had the same problem, and the proposed fix worked well. Unfortunately, I also had several 3rd party libraries that were compiled with the older version of MSVC. So, the program still crashed. In my case, updating the MSVC to the newest version has helped. One can download the latest MSCV from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170
